# Can I change value of attribute in UiPath.Core.UiElement

Tags: uielement, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I have a checkbox that I can't click on, but at the same time, I can get its UiElement. When the checkbox is clicked, the tag 'text=checked' in another case 'text-unchecked'. Can I set the value of an attribute without click of the checkbox?

Comment: Can you show the example. Could you code this here or on Codepen maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'Check' activity? If it doesn't work I think you should try 'Set Text'.